# MEF attribute-less property importing with contract name

Tags: c#, mef

I find the lambda expressions needed for importing of properties somewhat confusing and I am trying to also understand how to use MEF conventions for importing and exporting so maybe I am trying to take on too much at once.

I am exporting `ResourceDictionary` with a contract name which I imported previously like this:

```
[ImportMany("ApplicationResources", typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
public IEnumerable<ResourceDictionary> Views { get; set; }
```

Which works well and is fine, however I am now trying to import this via a `RegistrationBuilder` but not fully understanding how to do this.

This exports them I believe (but I have to be honest I don't fully understand the syntax):

```
var registration = new RegistrationBuilder();
registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<ResourceDictionary>()
    .Export<ResourceDictionary>(x => x.AsContractName("ApplicationResources"));
```

I have a property in my `App` that I wish to populate

So tried this (carried out within the App itself)

```
registration.ForType<App>()
    .ImportProperty<ResourceDictionary>(x => x.Views);
```

But this isn't working and I am guessing I need to set contract name somehow? Can anyone tell me what the syntax for this is? Maybe if I can see the correc syntax I can better understand how it works... I hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it turns out that I found the solution after posting the question. I don't tend to answer my own questions but as it had me stuch for a while and in case it helps anyone else this is what works:

```
registration.ForType<App>()
    .ImportProperty<ResourceDictionary>(x => x.Views, ib => ib.AsContractName("ApplicationResources"));
```

However this only works if I use `SafisfyImportsOnce` rather than `ComposeParts` which I am slightly confused about